# NADH generated by glycolysis must be oxidized back to NAD+ in order for glycolysis to continue. What three positive pathways exist for this to occur?

Tags: cell-biology

I know where NAD+ is reduced to NADH but don't have the slightest clue as to three pathways where NADH is oxidized to NAD+. 
If you could give me some guidance that would be great!